# how to use the recursion in factorial?My coding is withou factorial

Tags: java, recursion

hello sir my coding is here..i want a simple coding of factorial using recursion

```
int n=4;
int fact=1;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    fact=fact*i;
}
System.out.println("i"+fact);
```

Comment: What do you understand about recursion at the moment?  And how far have you come in trying to implement this so far?  It'd be easy enough to splat down some sample code, but the main thing is that *you* should pick up the **principles**, such that you can write the actual code yourself.

Comment: Usually Factorial of n goes down to 1 by default, but you have declare a `fact` variable here. Do you want a recursion to go down to defined level?

Answer (score 4):

```
public int factorial (int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
      return 1;

    else return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

Comment: `return (n>0)?(n*factorial(n-1):1;`

Comment: Of course you can write it like that, but if somebody doesn't understand the concept of recursion, you might not want to introduce more stuff that makes the subject at hand harder to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int F(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return n * F(n-1);
}
```